# Difficulty in making eyes for my character?

Tags: rendering

[image][image]I am trying to create a character with the help of a you tube tut, but I am facing difficulty in extruding eyes, though I believe that I have completely followed the tut but still it's not working. Can anyone help me please? I have uploaded pictures for you refence as well and the picture from the tut as well. If anyone can help then please.

Comment: maybe instead of extruding + scaling he has insetted (press i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are just lacking a tiny step to get the same result. After extruding (your second image) try scaling down the selection a bit : press S then move the mouse as needed.

Comment: That worked. thank you